# smartFix: Not all images have the 'Mailbody' flag set

Tags: ocr

After a retransfer of a stack to another subsystem, there is a analyse failure "Not all images have the 'Mailbody' flag set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**
The problem is, if you combine the mailbody and an attachment to one document, the Analyser could not handle that. The Analyser assume that mailbody and attachment are always two separat documents.

**Solution**
Remove the mailbody flag before retransfer the stack.

```
SETPAGE_ATTR(docindex, 'MailBody', FALSE, pageNumberFrom, pageNumberTo);
```